# How to Charge Our Devices in this Machine?

Tags: lateral-thinking, real

***Warning**: It is actually a simple "puzzle" which is silly but debatably unique as it really happens to me in real life.*

---

I'm amazed with nowadays technology. When I go to one of the shopping mall in Singapore, I found this: **a public charging station with fingerprint lock system**! *(Well, at least I'm amazed because I couldn't find something like this in my origin country, lol.)*

[image]

On this machine, there are 10 slots (labeled 1 to 10 from up to down) for charging and a single monitor screen. One slot is strictly restricted to be used by only one device. The slot color light denotes if the slot is used or not: **red** means used and **green** means unused.

The procedure of the machine is like this (for simplicity of the puzzle):

- There are 2 options on the screen: "Charge" or "Collect". "Charge" only available to be chosen if not all slots are red, likewise "Collect" only available if not all slots are green.
- *If user choose "Charge":*

  - The user is asked to tap his/her finger on fingerprint device 4 times.
  - If all of those 4 fingerprints are similar, **the first fingerprint** will try to be saved in its database. If all of those are not similar, the screen will show error "*Different fingerprints detected!*" then go back to the beginning of procedure.
  - If the fingerprint is not in current database, the fingerprint is then saved and the **uppermost** green slot will be open. But, if it is already in current database, the screen will show error "*Only 1 device/person is allowed!*" then go back to the beginning of procedure.
  - After the slot is opened, the user is supposedly to charge his/her device inside the slot.
  - The user then close the slot, the slot's color will change to **red**. It then goes to the beginning of the procedure.
- *If user choose "Collect":*

  - The user is asked to tap his/her finger on fingerprint once.
  - If it matches with any fingerprint on the database, then the respective slot will open. The user supposedly take his/her device out. After the user close the slot, the slot's color will change to **green** and the fingerprint is **removed** from the database. It then goes to the beginning of the procedure.
  - If it doesn't match with any fingerprint on the database, the screen will simply show error "Fingerprint is not matched!" then go back to the beginning of procedure.

---

I and 2 of my friends (say B and C) want to charge our devices. The machine shows all of 10 slots are green. B chooses "Charge" and taps his finger, then slot 1 is opened. Unluckily, **the charge cable on this slot doesn't work**! B then closes the slot, it turned red. We don't know how the logic works before, so B tries to collect then charge again (with his finger), willingly another slot is opened. But of course, slot 1 is opened again.

Now this is the fun part. B closes the slot, it turned red. C then chooses "Charge" on the screen and tap his finger. The slot 2 is opened, but, C asks B to charge B's device on this slot. C closes the slot then asks me to choose "Charge" and tap my finger. The slot 3 is opened, then C puts his device on this slot and closes the slot.

At the current state, slots 1 to 3 is red and my device is still on my pocket. Slot 1 uses B's fingerprint, slot 2 uses C's fingerprint, and slot 3 uses my fingerprint. But somehow, we then successfully manage to charge all of our devices. How?

Comment: You know you have ten eligible fingers each right...

Comment: @theonetruepath Not necessarily;  the puzzle *is* tagged "lateral-thinking".  For all we know, A, B, and C might be single-fingered aliens.  ;)

Comment: Is [**this**](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Oude_stekkerdoos.jpg) too much for lateral thinking.

Comment: As a Singaporean, I have to confess that I have never seen any of these things before. I also find it hard to imagine the average Singaporean willing to part from their smartphones for long enough to use these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You all

> use your other fingers to unlock the other slots :|
>
>  Those devices sound like they take one finger to open a box, so you can easily open the other slots by using other fingers

Or maybe

> You didn't say you charge them all at the same time. Just take turns using slots 2 and 3 :)

Comment: but.. but.. single-fingered aliens!  ;D

Comment: Just.. just one finger total? not even one in each arm? not even toes? gosh, poor mono-appendage creatures :'(

Comment: The real puzzle is how the single-fingered aliens manage to plug charging cables into their phones.

Comment: Yeah, i was about to comment on how inconvenient it must be to operate a phone when you only have one finger... but then i realized that the question never did mention anything about phones. Just 'devices' ;)

Comment: Yes, the correct answer is, indeed, using other finger... Funny when the screen shows *"Only 1 device/person is allowed!"* error meanwhile we can use up to 10 (or 20?) slots. Welp.

Answer (score 0):

> B opens the broken slot 1 again as a 'trap' for an unsuspecting 4th person/1-fingered alien.

> They will be assigned the broken slot #1 and after figuring out the charger is broken, you can - even without lying - tell them you tried as well, but unfortunately it's broken and hope they won't bother to once again unlock their slot. (Why would they?)

> This allows slot #4 to be used and also all other 6 slots can now be used and reused over and over again throughout the day as long as the poor holder of #1 does not return or the machine is somehow reset/emptied by staff.

> The question remains whether it's ethical to let 1 phonebattery die to save so many others.

Comment: Personally, I would simply have left slot one locked without a device in it using my left thumb and moved on to the next slot.